# Is "found a secure work situation" a good expression for "found a stable job"?

Tags: phrase-usage

[image]

I'm learning IELTS writing. Here is one sentence in the example essay:

> It is clear that nearly one-tenth of the graduates had not found a secure work situation, indicated by the "unemployment" category (12%).

I think "found a secure work situation" is not a good expression for "get a job", am I right?

Comment: 12% isn't "nearly one-tenth"! It's more than one tenth.

Comment: Yes, thank you. And do you think "not found a secure work situation" is a great way to describe "unemployed"? Does it sound natural to a native speaker?

Answer (score 1):

I'd agree that the expression was a bit vague if it simply meant 'a job'. A "work situation" could mean anything from employment, to self employment, to an apprenticeship. It could even be used to refer to a work environment more than the work itself.

But, in the context, I think the writer has chosen a broader expression because not all the options could be described as "a job", yet they are arguably 'employment' (generally thought of as "remunerative work" - something that occupies your time and you are paid for). For example, your chart shows postgrad studies as being a kind of employment (because all the categories on the visual are opposed to 'unemployment'), presumably because many postgrad studies are funded research and those involved get paid, yet they are fixed-term and are not really a 'job' (which Oxford defines as "a paid position of *regular* employment").

Comment: @Jesse No I don't think you're correct in this context - i've updated my answer to reflect what I see in your visual

Comment: Thank you, I get it.